# implementing quicksort in c

Tags: c, quicksort

```
void qkSort (int *arr,int size)
{
    if (size>1)
    {
        int p = partition(arr,size);
    qkSort(arr,p);
    qkSort(arr+p+1,size-(p-1));
    }
    return;
}

int partition(int *arr,int size)
{
    int i,j,pivot,temp;
    pivot = size-1;
    for(i=0,j=-1;i<size-1;++i)
    {   
        if (arr[i]<arr[pivot])
        {
             ++j;
             if(i!=j)
             {
                 temp = arr[i];
                 arr[i] = arr[j];
                 arr[j] = temp;
             }
        }
    }

    temp = arr[pivot];
    arr[pivot] = arr[j+1];
    arr[j+1] = temp;

    pivot = j+1;

    return pivot;
}
```

The program hangs up. Monitoring the variables by gdb shows that the second recursive call doesnt get its argument passed correctly. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a declaration for `partition` visible from `qkSort` where you call it? If not, your compiler should have warned you; crank up its warning levels. In this particular case that shouldn't cause any visible problems, but you should *always* have a visible prototype for any function you call.

Comment: @Keith Thompson
I have used multiple files. The declarations are present in a separate header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the size of 2nd array is wrong.

```
qkSort(arr+p+1,size-(p-1));
```

**This will work.**

```
qkSort(arr+p+1,(size-p)-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to: http://p2p.wrox.com/visual-c/66347-quick-sort-c-code.html

This example should help you get started.

Comment: The code referred by you needs 3 arguments, a pointer to the array, and the first and last indices. However isn't there a way to work with just two arguments, the pointer and the size of the array?